# Does auto deduce the type at compile time or runtime in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

Consider the following

```
auto a = 10;
```

When does the compiler know that `a` is an `int`, at compile time or at run-time? If it deduces the type at run-time, will it not affect the performance?

Comment: It doesn't affect run-time performance at all.

Comment: `c` and `c++` are statically typed. All types must be known at compile-time. `auto` could not require run-time type checking, as it is part of `c++`.

Comment: @Rubens unless we deal with RTTI though..

Comment: @vines That means if I use typeid?

Comment: @pranitkothari or `dynamic_cast<>`

Comment: @pranitkothari yes, `typeid` and `dynamic_cast<>`.

Comment: Do you know why it is called "compiled time"? The compiler does not "know" anything post compile time.

Comment: this is just Syntactic Sugar, so this is compile time completely

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Compile time. In C++, runtime type information is stripped during compilation(without RTTI or virtual inheritance). It is not possible, in fact, to inspect the primitive type at runtime.

Answer (score 25):

I just wanted to add some things that the other answers didn't address.

1. every declaration must have a known type at compile time so `auto` doesn't get special treatment, it has to deduce the type at compile time.
2. You are sort of mis interpreting how `auto` should be used. Yes you can do `auto i = 2;` and it works fine. But a situation where you need auto is a lambda for example. A lambda does not have a namable type (although you can assign it to an `std::function`). Another situation it is useful for is inside a class or function template it can be extremely difficult to figure out the type of certain operations (maybe sometimes impossible), for example when a function is called on a template type that function may return something different depending on the type given, with multiple types this can become essentially impossible to figure out which type it will return. You could of course just wrap the function in a `decltype` to figure out the return but an `auto` is much cleaner to write.
3. People also seem to use auto quite a bit for iterators because their types are quite a pain to write but I'm not so sure this is an intended primary use of `auto`

Comment: :+1, I like your first and second point, but 3. code need to write while using iterator is clumsy, so it will defiantly make code more readable.

Comment: @pranitkothari I wasn't saying you shouldn't do it I'm just saying it's not the reason why `auto` was added, people were using iterators long before it

Comment: and people were writing iterators incorrectly and/or avoiding them before auto.  auto makes correct code easier to write

Comment: @MooingDuck I use it for iterators too

Comment: Herb Sutter seems to think that it is ok to use `auto` for convenience purposes [in the article "elements of modern c++ style"](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/)

Comment: @daramarak not so sure I fully agree with that, why is `auto i = 2` a good thing. Let's say you wanted it to be a long and you wrote that. Then you call a function with an overload for long and an overload for int. It will select the int overload which is wrong, and no warning will ever be issued

Comment: @aaronman Sutter explicitly says in the article "If you want to explicitly enforce a type conversion, that’s okay; state the target type. " which is just the case for the above case. Don't get me wrong, I see that the above case might cause problem even for seasoned programmer, but most cases are not like this, and in those cases it is just practical to use them, and even members of the c++ committee encourages the use of them.

Comment: Nod to dramarak. Almost always use auto: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: Actually, the absurd inconvenience of using iterator types was one of the primary use cases of `auto`, being the first motivating example in one of the oldest proposals for it, back in 2003, long before lambdas were properly designed: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1478.pdf

Comment: On the point of point 3, I'll quote Bjarne directly from his book, TC++PL4,
"Using auto, we avoid redundancy and writing long type names. This is especially important in
generic programming where the exact type of an object can be hard for the programmer to know
and the type names can be quite long".
This address both concerns, that is 1) The intended purpose, which is when the type is unknown, and 2) A side benefit which is to circumvent long type names.

Answer (score 9):

It's done completely at compile time, with no performance difference.

```
auto i = 2;
```

compiles the same as

```
int i = 2;
```

Comment: In other examples there might be a performance difference. auto is guaranteed never to do a type conversion, so it is always at least as fast, if not faster.

Answer (score 8):

The type of the variable declared `auto` is done at compile time, which means if you have the following snippet of code:

```
auto i = 10; // i is an integer
i = 3.14; // i is still an integer, will truncate to 3
```

Herb Sutter (The guy currently in charge of the C++ standardization committee) recommends to "Use auto wherever possible. It is useful for two reasons. First, most obviously it’s a convenience that lets us avoid repeating a type name that we already stated and the compiler already knows.  Second, it’s more than just a convenience when a type has an unknown or unutterable name, such as the type of most lambda functions, that you couldn’t otherwise spell easily or at all." (see [this](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) post on his blog). The intended use of `auto` is to make things easier on the developer, so feel free to use it whenever it seems to fit.

Comment: There is a third situation you didn't describe: when the type changes but the code doesn't. This happens when we are developing functions for containers, since they frequently have similar or identical interfaces, so the code hardly changes, so, if we change the type, the code automatically adapts to those changes - no retyping. auto really helps developing in those situations.

Comment: I'm sure that Herb Sutter is "knowing what he does" concerning programming in C++. I'm convinced that the compiler deduces the correct type whenever I use `auto`. However, I'm not convinced that I'm always knowing what the compiler deduces and whether it matches completely my expectation. Therefore I prevent the use of `auto` whenever I'm able to. (I remember a time (though its decades ago) when explicity of source code was counted as modern and improvement.)

Comment: Having slept a night over this I awoke in the morning and suddenly realized: I became an old-fashioned type-writer...

Answer (score 2):

C++ is a statically typed language. Types cannot be determined at runtime. The type of every expression must be known at compile time. Even when a variable is declared auto, its type is fixed at compile time.