# Does auto in C++ 11 make compile time longer?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

```
auto abc = 5566;
```

As far as I know, compiler knows `abc` is `int` at compile time so it will not affect runtime performance.

However, does it makes compile time longer??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might take a nanosecond longer.

Comment: @rightfold or a nanosecond less.

Comment: The compiler has to know the type of the initializer anyway.

Comment: Hardware is cheap, programmers ain't.

Comment: i think it will be shorter instead of longer. because it don't need to check type of `abc` is same as `5566`

Comment: Most likely it is exactly the same [aside from the extra character of source code to read, which will most likely add several instructions to the execution time of the compiler, but so will adding a comment, or some such - and you can't really tell the difference there, can you?]

Comment: Write a program that emits 1,000,000 auto or typed variables, #include it a time the compilation of each 30x, discard the best and worst of each, average the result and ... have your answer?

Comment: @kfsone - OP wanted to know if type deduction by compiler takes some measurable time. Seems pretty logical and also deserved 4 upvotes in duplicate answer.

Comment: MArking it as duplicate. Oh, and yeah, it is a very good/valid question.

Comment: @schepurin I upvoted, I was suggesting a way to test, because the answer likely varies between compilers and how they implement it. A while back I found that `#include <string>` was adding 26 seconds per 100 compilation units to a gcc build this way.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`auto` is one character longer than `int`, so the lexer definitely has to do more work.

On the other hand, the compiler no longer has to check that the user provided an appropriate type, so my best guess is that `auto` will be slightly faster.

In the end, you should probably not decide between type inference and explicit typing based on performance considerations. Intent and clarity should be the deciding factors.

Comment: "`auto` is one character longer than `int`, so the lexer definitely has to do more work." - I believe we have a winner here.

Comment: What about if `int` is followed by ten spaces but `auto` is only followed by one? :-) Still, damn funny.

Comment: If we're worried about the work the lexer has to do, what's in a typical "auto usage case" where the type is something like  `std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>>::const_iterator`?

Comment: OTOH with auto, the compiler will still have to deduce the type - taking time - and _then_ have to store the initializer for it. I would say `auto` is likely slightly _slower_

Comment: @sehe The compiler already knows the type of the initializer. Otherwise, it couldn't give you compiler errors if you get the type of the variable wrong.

Comment: @FredOverflow Mmmm. You could be right. If I were writing the compiler, I'd then emit metadata/instructions for the declaration using the same code path, making it a break-even, but yeah, it's likely not going to be longer.

Answer (score 3):

It may, or it may not, it depends on the compiler. Certainly the performance of this is not something mandated by the standard.

Since the lexical analyser knows the type of `5566` anyway, it's likely to be largely irrelevant.

You'd be better off worrying about more "macro" issues like algorithm and data structure selection. You'll almost certainly get a better return on investment than worry about whether auto type selection is faster or not.

Use of `auto` in creating variables is not so much about performance as it is about making your life easier as a coder.

Answer (score 1):

As when compiling, the compiler has to check the type anyway I think that it will not take significantly more time to replace the auto by what the compiler found as type.

if you want some further information: [C++ 11 auto compile time or runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618759/c-11-auto-compile-time-or-runtime)

if you want to know if you should use auto: [How much is too much with C++11 auto keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434971/how-much-is-too-much-with-c0x-auto-keyword)