# Does auto deduce types in compile time or run time in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, c++14

I googled and found a solution in stackoverflow [C++ 11 auto compile time or runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19618759/5756174). It is an duplicate but not entirely, the answer stated there was compile time. Is it really compile time? Let us consider the below example.

```
auto give_something(bool mybool)
{
    if (mybool)
        return string("auto");
    return 6.66f;
}

int main()
{
    bool mybool = (rand() % 2) ? true : false;
    auto x = give_something(mybool); // how type of x is deduced?
    return 0;
}
```

Here the type of `x` and return type of `give_something` **can't be deduced while compiling** (my assumption). It should be deduced only at run time. So `auto` compile time or run time or both?

Comment: `Does auto deduce types in compile time or run time in C++11?`: **At compile time**, it follows the rules of template argument deduction with a few exceptions.

Comment: All types must be known by the compiler at time of compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto` works at compile time.

You are correct that the return type of `give_something` can't be deduced at compile-time. In such a case, your code will not compile. Clang gives this error message for your example:

```
main.cpp:8:5: error: 'auto' in return type deduced as 'float' here but deduced 
                      as 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' in earlier return 
                      statement
    return 6.66f;
```

Comment: I didn't compiled and check just my thought.

Comment: @jblixr I'd suggest attempting to compile the code next time, as your compiler would essentially give you the answer.

Comment: So using `auto` I cannot return two different types from a function.

Comment: @jblixr Nope. You can't return different types from a function at all.