# Reuse of variable of type auto

Tags: c++, auto

I have a special class to be used as return type of methods, containing the wanted value or in case of failure an error message which is even cascading from earlier errors. It works as expected.

As the returned type is differently complex I like to use the keyword auto. But when using a lot of methods I have to create new return variables.

A typical part of code looks like this:

```
auto ret1 = methodA();
if(ret1.isValid()...

auto ret2 = methodB();
if(ret2.isValid()...
```

I dont like to always create a new variable. But I like the elegant way of error handling. Using a more dump return type like an error code in integer would solve the problem but then I have no benefit from the error handling return type.

Is there any trick to reuse the first return variable `ret1`?

Comment: Are they the same type? If yes, then simply `ret1 = methodB()`, if no, then no, since `ret1` would have a type already.

Comment: Auto is calculated at compilation time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618759/c-11-auto-compile-time-or-runtime

Comment: `auto` is just a replacement for the actual type, there is not much more magic behind it. Hence if `methodA` and `methodB` return something different the answer is no. In other words you can replace `auto` with the actual type and your problem would still be the same

Comment: You could let `isValid` take a callable that get's called only if the value is valid. Then you wouldn't need to store the return value at all. Depends a lot on your use case thoug if it's suitable. Lambdas make passing inline callables very easy and readable.

Comment: Why don't you like to always create a new variable? Are your objects very large?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is not a type.

It is a keyword, that says "put the type here for me, by *deducing* it from the initial value". That occurs during compilation, once.

You cannot reuse `ret1` to store an object of a different type, whether you use `auto` or not.

This shouldn't really be a problem. If you're concerned about "running out of names", or "having many similar names", your names are not descriptive enough and/or your scopes aren't tight enough.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to create new scopes to reuse the variable name for a different variable, like:

```cpp
{
    auto ret = methodA();
    if (ret.isValid()) ...
}
{
    auto ret = methodB();
    if (ret.isValid()) ...
}
```

You can also take advantage of the scope created by `if`, placing the init-statement inside:

```cpp
if (auto ret = methodA(); ret.isValid()) ...

if (auto ret = methodB(); ret.isValid()) ...
```

Comment: The latter requires C++17. Before that `if(auto ret = methodA())` with conversion-to-bool defined for the return type as replacement for `isValid()` might work well.

Comment: FWIW I've been using the latter pattern loads lately and it's lovely.

Answer (score 2):

`auto` is *not* a type. In `auto foo = bar();` the compiler simply figures out what type `bar()` actually returns and substitutes that in. So if `bar()` returns `int` then that's the type of `foo`, if it returns `bool` then *that* is the type of `foo`. And once the type that `auto` should be replaced with (the first time) has been determined, then it can *never* change. `auto` doesn't mean "variable type" it just means "hey compiler, I'm too lazy to figure out the type to put here, please do it for me", but there is *no difference what-so-ever* compared to you just writing the final type yourself.
So, you can reuse the variable if what you assign to it the second time is of the same type as the first time - otherwise not.

Comment: And, to be honest, I've been cautious about latching on the terminology "reuse the variable", because you can't ever even do that; an object is an object is an object. You can't replace an object by reusing a name that's in scope. But with the appropriate assignment semantics you can mutate it using another object as source material ;) Might sound like nitpicking but I think it comes down to how people understand the "identity" of objects and that `=` does not replace an object or create a new one. Granted, at some level of abstraction, we can think of it that way if the ass. op's done right.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I know the details. I'm trying to provide a simple, down to earth, explanation that will resonate with a newbie. If we get too technical the basic point often gets lost on non-experts.

Comment: I know you know, I'm just dropping it there for others and possibly for a bit of nudging on wording so we don't accidentally mislead/misteach people. Sorry.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Nothing to be "Sorry" about.

Comment: Great, I'm glad. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I dont like to always create a new variable.

Much better is to create a `const` variable:

```
const auto ret1 = methodA();
if(ret1.isValid()...

const auto ret2 = methodB();
if(ret2.isValid()...
```

In this case you need to make `const` all the methods like `isValid`, but that is even better: "is" shouldn't have side effects and modify the state.

Next step is to remove the temp variable at all:

```
if(methodA().isValid()) {
    ...
}

if(methodB().isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

The alternative is to wrap each function call into a block:

```
{
    const auto ret = methodA();
    if(ret.isValid()...
}

{
    const auto ret = methodB();
    if(ret.isValid()...
}
```

This allows you to reuse the const variable name.

Each block becomes a candidate for extraction into a separate function (see Uncle Bob in "Clean Code").